# Translate XML into system properties using Scala

Tags: xml, scala

Using Scala, what is the best approach for converting

```
<myapp>
  <username>bill</username>
  <password>secret123</password>
  <background>#FFFFFF</background>
</myapp>
```

into the following system properties:

```
myapp.username=bill
myapp.password=secret123
myapp.background=#FFFFFF
```

assuming the converter appends to sys.props?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scala> val s = "<myapp><username>bill</username><password>secret123</password><background>#FFFFFF</background></myapp>"
s: java.lang.String = <myapp><username>bill</username><password>secret123</password><background>#FFFFFF</background></myapp>

scala> val e = xml.XML.loadString(s)
e: scala.xml.Elem = <myapp><username>bill</username><password>secret123</password><background>#FFFFFF</background></myapp>

scala> val sp = new sys.SystemProperties
sp: scala.sys.SystemProperties = 
Map(env.emacs -> "", java.runtime.name -> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment, ....)

scala> sp ++= e.child.map(n => (e.label + "." + n.label, n.text))
res11: sp.type = 
Map(env.emacs -> "", java.runtime.name -> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment, ...)
```

Sanity check:

```
scala> val p = java.lang.System.getProperties
p: java.util.Properties = 
{env.emacs=, java.runtime.name=Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment,...}

scala> import collection.JavaConversions._
import collection.JavaConversions._

scala> p filter { case (k, v) => k.startsWith("myapp") } \
          foreach { case (k,v) => println(k + "=" + v) }
myapp.password=secret123
myapp.background=#FFFFFF
myapp.username=bill
```

Comment: Thanks, how could I handle deeper entries such as <username><secondary>william</secondary></username> to resolve to myapp.username.secondary=william ?

Comment: Is your XML going to be fixed (ie, only a small number of well-defined tags may be present)?  If so, then it might be easier to just do fixed XPath expressions.  For example val secondary = e \\ "secondary"; if (!secondary.isEmpty) sp += ("myapp.username.secondary", secondary.text)

Comment: Ideally would like it to be an open format but this is good too :)

Comment: You could adapt what I've done in the answer to an open format - you would need to make it recursive.  But the basic concepts/APIs would be the same.

Answer (score 1):

[java.util.Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) supports an XML format, thought not the one you describe.